# How to transpose a high-degree tensor in FP way?

Tags: math, recursion, permutation, transpose, tensor

I'm currently working on a [math library](https://github.com/WangNianyi2001/Math/blob/master/Math.js).
It's now supporting several matrix operations:

```
- Plus
- Product
- Dot
- Get & Set
- Transpose
- Multiply
- Determinant
```

I always want to generalize everything I can generalize

I was thinking about a recursive way to implement the transpose of a matrix, but I just couldn't figure it out.

Anybody help?

Comment: All matricies are not tensors.  Tensors follow specific transformation rules.  Tensors can be expressed as matricies, but not all matricies are tensors.  It's not germane to your question, but I thought I'd point it out any.

Comment: @duffymo But... Wikipedia says so... Am I understanding it incorrectly? (. _.)

Comment: I know a bit more about tensors than is captured in Wikipedia.  Yes, my point still stands.  You'll have a hard time writing matrix operations in a functional way.  They don't scale that way.

Comment: @duffymo Haha okay, thanks for pointing it out, dude! Let's say, ummm, how about "matrices in higher dimensions" ("higher-dimensional matrix" sounds like a matrix with a size bigger than 3*3), maybe "cubix"?

Comment: You're making up terms now.  Please stop.  It's up to you to understand the mathematics, not for the problem to adjust to you.  There are such things as fourth order tensors.

Comment: @duffymo Yeah, indeed... I just don't know what words should I use here.

Comment: You're talking about matricies and linear algebra.  Leave tensors out of it.  Most people on this site don't know what they are or how they're used, including you.  Matricies are more common.  Stick with that.

Comment: @duffymo I've added a claim at the top of this question.

Comment: Nope, you got it wrong again.  NONE OF THIS is pertinent to your question; irrelevant to the answer.  It feels like you only want to include it so you can feel clever for saying the word "tensor".  Do yourself a favor and take it out.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you against trying to write a recursive method to transpose a matrix.

The idea is easy:

```
transpose(A) = A(j,i)
```

Recursion isn't hard in this case.  You can see the stopping condition: a 1x1 matrix with a single value is its own transpose.  Build it up for 2x2, etc.

The problem is that this will be terribly inefficient, both in terms of stack depth and memory, for any matrix beyond a trivial size.  People who apply linear algebra to real problems can require tens of thousands or billions of degrees of freedom.

You don't talk about meaningful, practical cases like sparse or banded matricies, etc.

You're better off doing it using a straightforward declarative approach.

[Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix) use BLAS as its backing implementation.  It's a more functional language than JavaScript.  Perhaps you could crib some ideas by looking at the source code.

I'd recommend that you do the simple thing first, get it all working, and then branch out from there.

Here's a question to ask yourself: Why would anyone want to do serious numerical work using JavaScript?  What will your library offer that's an improvement on what's [available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linear-algebra)?

If you want to learn how to [reinvent wheels](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/10/14/in-defense-of-not-invented-here-syndrome/), by all means proceed.  Just understand that you aren't the first.

Comment: nah, I ain't doing it for anything, I just like it